# Haskell : How to sort a record type by one attribute if the other is same?

Tags: haskell, record, newtype

If I just have a very simple custom data type:

```
data Person = Person {first_name :: String,
                      last_name :: String
                     } deriving (Ord, Eq, Show)
```

If I have a list of these Person data types, and I want to sort it by `last_name` if and only if the `first_name` is the same. But I should **not** sort the `first_name`. Simply call the following obviously doesn't work.

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (sortBy)

sortBy (compare `on` last_name ) persons
```

How can I solve it? I do agree it's quite confusing. What I want is that if I have the following (that's definitely not a list of the custom data type, I just want to show it clearly)

```
[("c","d"),("a","c"),("a","a")]
```

After sorting I would like to have

```
[("c","d"),("a","a"),("a","c")]
```

instead of

```
 [("a","a"),("a","c"),("c","d")]
```

So the idea is that first element should still appear at first, since it does not have the same `first_name` with the other two. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: What if the two do not have the same `first_name`?

Comment: Then it should not be sorted. Thank you!

Comment: It isn't quite clear how you plan to sort only some elements and leave others unsorted. It doesn't compute. You can only sort an entire list.

Comment: A stable sort using a comparison function that treats all first names as equivalent should do the trick.

Comment: @chepner that's exactly what `compare \`on\` last_name` does, and OP  claims it doesn't work, and perhaps not because the default sort is unstable.

Comment: ``compare `on` last_name`` will compare two `Person`s by their last name, regardless of their first name. Unless the first names are equal, you want two `Person`s to compare as equal so that the stable sort won't alter their relative position.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison function you want is to treat two `Person` values as equal if their first names are different. If the first names are the same, *then* compare based on the last name.

Since `sort` in Haskell is stable, if an element `a` precedes an equal element `b` in the input, it will also precede `b` in the output. In this case, two elements with different first names will compare as equal, so `sort` will really only sort the consecutive subsequences sharing a first name.

There is probably a clever way to implement this, but a straightforward comparison function might look like

```
foo :: Person -> Person -> Ordering
foo x y | first_name x /= first_name y = EQ
        | otherwise                   = (comparing last_name) x y
```

Given `people = [ Person "A" "B",Person "Z" "C",Person "Z" "A"]`, you can see
the difference between `sortBy (comparing last_name)` and `sortBy foo`.

```
> people
[Person {first_name = "A", last_name = "B"},Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "C"},Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "A"}]
> sortBy (comparing last_name) people
[Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "A"},Person {first_name = "A", last_name = "B"},Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "C"}]
> sortBy foo people
[Person {first_name = "A", last_name = "B"},Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "A"},Person {first_name = "Z", last_name = "C"}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that's what I want, although it's a bit weird. But anyway, that's a weird question...

Comment: I think you meant `first_name x /= first_name y`? My preference would be to write this inline unless it’s going to be reused, e.g. `sortBy (\ a b -> case comparing first_name a b of { EQ -> comparing last_name a b; _ -> EQ })` or break out a helper function like `whenEqual EQ a = a; whenEqual _ _ = EQ` so you can write `whenEqual (comparing first_name a b) (comparing last_name a b)`; this can also be written pointfree as `liftA2 whenEqual <$> comparing first_name <*> comparing last_name`, although that’s maybe a bit too far, haha

Comment: This comparison doesn't impose an non-strict partial order. relation. John Blake is equivalent to Maria Hernandez, and Maria Hernandez is equivalent to John Browne, but John Browne is not equivalent to John Blake. The documentation doesn't say what `sortBy` should do with a comparison function that doesn't respect the non-strict partial order laws, and I'm having a hard time imagining what sorting with this comparison could ever mean.

Comment: Correction, Haskell 2010 report says "The function is assumed to define a total ordering", so it is undefined what `sortBy foo` will do.

Comment: Hm. If `sortBy` is guaranteed to be stable given a total ordering, does that imply anything about what calls to `foo` are made? If `foo a b == EQ`, we're left to imply that both `a <= b` and `b <= a` are true, but for sorting purposes that is, in some sense, *not* true, because `[b, a]` would be guaranteed to sort as `[b, a]`, not `[a, b]`. So `foo` itself does not define even a preorder (since we lack transitivity), but can it ever be used by `sortBy` in such a way to distinguish it from a total order?

Comment: Not much. If you are using merge sort, the final order will depend on where exactly you split the list, and whether you do any insertion passes.

Comment: Yes, but whether or not merge sort is stable depends on the implementation; Haskell (or at least GHC) `sort` is stated to have a stable implementation.

Comment: The traditional straightforward implementation (where you break the list into 'low' and 'high' parts) is stable. Tiimsort is also stable.